# How to make a position absolute & relative website, responsive

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

i'm having this problem where I have to make a site responsive, but when I view the site on different devices, the **Height** looks bad.

Basically I'm trying to make that my header always no matter the screen height size will be 85px, the main content can vary, and the footer 180px ('cause inside I have 3 rows with 60 each).

The thing is I don't want the site have y-scroll, so it has to fit perfectly (that's why the main content div can vary the size)

I have something like this
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-frog-cou89 some Chrome test mobile on console looks good but the old ones are really bad.

***Is there a way that I can make the site to be `max-height: 100%` on every device and the main content fix its size depend on the screen size of the mobile phone ? so the user can see all the footer info without scrolling down***
[image]

Comment: Please add the code you are using for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `height: calc(100vh - 85px - 180px);` for your main content element. This will work for any screen size.

(= full viewport height minus height of header and footer)

Important: If you use borders and/or padding in these elements, make sure to define `box-sizing: border-box` for all elements, for example with a universal selector (`*`). This will *include*  the borders and paddings in that calculation.

And finally: You don't need relative and absolute positioning at all for this - just leave all `position` settings at the default, i.e. erase them.

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-perlman-rr4dx

Comment: thanks ! it seems to work, i'll try this solution on monday to see how it goes with full content, will comeback to make sure to give you the correct answer if so.
I have the positions absolute and relatives because when the user open his keyboard on any phone it moves the footer to the top, and position:fixed bottom:0 didn't work.
I'm pretty sure the code has box sizing, hope it works ! thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First use flexbox. Use vh (view height) for width and height, which will adjust to any device, but only on your root element. After that use %

```
.ui {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
}

.ui .header {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui .footer {
    height: 130px;
    width: 100%;
}

.ui .main {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
    width: 100%;
}
```